# Calling withMiddlewareAuthRequired using custom Auth0Server instance in next.js

Tags: next.js, auth0

In my next.js project, I cannot use the default environment variable names expected by the auth0 library, and thus want to instantiate my own Auth0Server, providing it with my custom environment variables to set the required configs (auth0 secret, client ID, etc.). Additionally, I use a `middelware.js` file to specify protected routes, by exporting `withMiddlewareAuthRequired` therein. When using the default naming convention (in the development environment), I do not need to instantiate my own Auth0Server and can use default imports and everything works as expected.

Implementing it to the best of my knowledge (see MWE below), results in an error

```
- error node_modules/oidc-token-hash/lib/shake256.js (3:0) @ <unknown>
- error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
null
```

which I think comes from the fact that I'm indirectly importing a auth0 library file from my `middleware.js` file. I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental, but how can I achieve the same thing using a custom Auth0Server instance?

To recreate a minimal working (or not working) example, I simply called `npx create-next-app`, chose all default values, installed `@auth0/nextjs-auth0` version `3.1.0`, and added/modified the files below.

- Next.js version 13.4.19

```js
// file src/pages/_app.tsx

import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  )
}
```

```js
// file src/auth0.js
// DEFAULT (working)

// Nothing to be added.

// CUSTOM (not working)
import { initAuth0 } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
const auth0 = initAuth0({
    baseURL: process.env.CUSTOM_AUTH0_BASE_URL,
    clientID: process.env.CUSTOM_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CUSTOM_AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    issuerBaseURL: process.env.CUSTOM_AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
    secret: process.env.CUSTOM_AUTH0_SECRET
});

export {auth0};
```

```js
// file src/pages/api/auth/[...auth0].js

// DEFAULT (working)
// import { handleAuth } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
// export default handleAuth();

// CUSTOM (not working)
import { auth0 } from '@/auth0';
export default auth0.handleAuth();
```

```js
// file src/middleware.js
// DEFAULT (working)
// import { withMiddlewareAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/edge';
// export default withMiddlewareAuthRequired();
// export const config = {
//     matcher: [
//         '/((?!api|favicon.ico|logo-dark.jpg).*)'
//     ]
// };

// CUSTOM (not working)
import { auth0 } from '@/auth0';
export default auth0.withMiddlewareAuthRequired();
export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/((?!api|favicon.ico|logo-dark.jpg).*)'
    ]
};
```

```
// file .env.local
// DEFAULT (working)
// AUTH0_BASE_URL="value"
// AUTH0_CLIENT_ID="value"
// AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET="value"
// AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL="value"
// AUTH0_SECRET="value"

// CUSTOM (not working)
CUSTOM_AUTH0_BASE_URL="value"
CUSTOM_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID="value"
CUSTOM_AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET="value"
CUSTOM_AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL="value"
CUSTOM_AUTH0_SECRET="value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your instance of the SDK with a middleware-compatible (Edge runtime compatible) initialiser. Instead of:

`import { initAuth0 } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0"`;

use:

`import { initAuth0 } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/edge"`.